# MySQL query combine 1 condition and its negative condition

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select message from MessagesList where SchemeName="like" or SchemeName!="like" ORDER BY Rand() limit 5;
```

I'm not getting a reliable output always with this. I want only 1 message for that scheme and rest 4 shouldn't be in that scheme. The purpose is to serve a multiple choice questions system where the user picks the correct one for each scheme.

Comment: could you share your expected output ? and data from your table ?

Comment: geuss you mean you want unique random records?

Comment: `SchemeName="like" or SchemeName!="like"` is always `TRUE`. [*tertium non datur*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a [`UNION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/union.html) to combine two separate queries:

```
(SELECT message FROM MessagesList WHERE SchemeName='like')
UNION ALL
(SELECT message FROM MessagesList WHERE SchemeName!='like' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4)
ORDER BY RAND() -- to ensure correct answer is randomly positioned in resultset
```

Comment: I think you are missing a `limit 1` from the first query.

Comment: You need to add LIMIT 1 to the first SELECT query otherwise, it will return all that satisfies that condition. You're right, Gordon. I edited that answer but it got rejected after peer review.

Comment: I had *assumed* that there could only be one correct answer for a given question.  If multiple correct answers might exist, then yes you may wish to add `LIMIT 1` to the first query if you wish to only serve a single correct answer to the user—but perhaps you want to serve them all... these are business decisions, that I leave to you @Rosemary.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one message that is "like", you can do this in one step:

```
select m.*
from messageslist m
order by (SchemeName = 'like') desc, rand()
limit 5;
```

You do need an additional subquery if you want to randomize the results in SQL.